# Broadcast message across conversations

Tags: c#, botframework

I want to broadcast message across conversations where the bot is present, issuing a command like that:

```
/broadcast gameid=15 message
```

For each conversation where is the bot, I save activity.Conversation.Id in state of the conversation and when the bot receive the command `/broadcast`, it extract all the state of the conversation, filter with the required criteria and `sendActivityAsync` to all chat using Conversation.Id retrieved in states.

```
 var activity = new Activity()
 {
     Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: state.ConversationId),
     Text = "toto",
     Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
     ServiceUrl = turnContext.Activity.ServiceUrl,
     ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId
 };
 await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(activity);
```

But the message is issued only in the chat where the command had been issued, ignoring the `Conversation.Id` I've setup in the activity.

I do my tests with the bot emulator.

So, is it possible to send activity from a chat to another and if so, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to send proactive messages to all of your users. Proactive messages in the BotFramework v4 SDK enable you to continue conversations with individual users or send them notifications.

To send proactive messages outside the scope of a conversation, you first need to get the conversation reference and save the resulting value in some persistent storage such as a database. You can get the reference from the `turnContext` in on `onTurnAsync` by calling:

```
var conversation = turnContext.Activity.GetConversationReference();
```

Then in your script to broadcast messages you can retrieve all the conversation references from storage, configure a new adapter, and call the `ContinueConversationAsync` method from the adapter and send an activity in the callback for each reference to message users.

```
await adapter.ContinueConversationAsync(botId, reference, async (turnContext) => {
    await turnContext.SendActivityAsync("Broadcast Message");
} , cancellationToken);
```

For more information about proactive messages, take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) and this [proactive messages example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) in Microsoft's BotBuilder-Samples repository on GitHub. Hope this is helpful.